# spaCy Example object format for SpanCategorizer

Tags: initialization, spacy

I am having an issue with SpanCategorizer that I believe is due to my Example object format and possible its initialization.
Can someone provide a very simple Example object with the correct format? Just an example with two docs and two labels will make it for me.
I am not getting how the `prediction` and the `reference` should look like. There is a *gold standard* mentioned in spacy documentation, but it looks out-of-date because the line `reference = parse_gold_doc(my_data)` doesn't work. Thanks so much for your help!

Here is the code I am using to annotate the docs:

````
``` phrase_matches = phrase_matcher(doc)
    
    # Initializing SpanGroups
    for label in labels:
        doc.spans[label]=[]
    
    # phrase_matches detection and labeling of spans, and generation of SpanGrups for each doc
    for match_id, start, end in phrase_matches:
            match_label = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
            span        = doc[start:end]
            span        = Span(doc, start, end, label = match_label)
            
            # Set up of the SpanGroup for each doc, for the different labels
            doc.spans[match_label].append(span) ```
````

However spaCy is not recognizing my labels.

Comment: You usually do not have to explicitly create Example objects, can you give an example of your code? Also the current docs shouldn't have `parse_gold_doc` any more, where did you see that? Check the training data docs if you haven't yet: https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added the code above. I believe it follows the link you send in the sense that I have added to the docs the annotations. However, I am not able to make spaCy recognize my labels. There is not a template for the config with spancat. How can I pass the labels to spaCy? Thanks much for your help.

Comment: I saw `parse_gold_doc` in the first example here: https://spacy.io/api/example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want/need to create `Example` objects directly, the easiest way to do so is to use the function [`Example.from_dict`](https://spacy.io/api/example#from_dict), which takes a `predicted` doc and a `dict`. `predicted` in this context is a `Doc` with partial annotations, representing data from previous components. For many use-cases, it can just be a "clean" doc created with `nlp.make_doc(text)`:

```
from spacy.training import Example
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
text = "I like London and Berlin"
span_dict = {"spans": {"my_spans": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC"), (7, 24, "DOUBLE_LOC")]}}
predicted = nlp.make_doc(text)
eg = Example.from_dict(predicted, span_dict)
```

What this function does, is taking the annotations from the `dict` and using those to define the gold-standard that is now stored in the `Example` object `eg`.

If you print this object (using spaCy >= 3.4.2), you'll see the internal representation of those gold-standard annotations:

> {'doc_annotation': {'cats': {}, 'entities': ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 'spans': {'my_spans': [(7, 13, 'LOC', ''), (18, 24, 'LOC', ''), (7, 24, 'DOUBLE_LOC', '')]}, 'links': {}}, 'token_annotation': {'ORTH': ['I', 'like', 'London', 'and', 'Berlin'], 'SPACY': [True, True, True, True, False], 'TAG': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'LEMMA': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'POS': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'MORPH': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'HEAD': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'DEP': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'SENT_START': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}}

PS: the `parse_gold_doc` function in the docs is just a placeholder/dummy function. We'll clarify that in the docs to avoid confusion!

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes sense to me. So hlepful :) It has been difficult to find detailed documentation on SpanCat, with complete examples to implement in the Jupyter lab. Do you recommend any source? I would like to be able to see examples of how to aggregate the examples and pass them to the pipeline. I am using SpanCat first, to help in doing textcat later. Any inputs would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sofie, when I run your example code without any modification, `eg` doesn't show the 'spans' in the span_dict. This is what I get:  `{'doc_annotation': {'cats': {}, 'entities': ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 'links': {}}, 'token_annotation': {'ORTH': ['I', 'like', 'London', 'and', 'Berlin'], 'SPACY': [True, True, True, True, False], 'TAG': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'LEMMA': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'POS': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'MORPH': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'HEAD': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'DEP': ['', '', '', '', ''], 'SENT_START': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}}`.  What is missing?

Comment: What version of spaCy do you have installed? Perhaps try updating to a newer one?

Comment: I have 3.4.1. Will try updating it.

Comment: Tried `pip install -U spacy`, but still shows same version 3.4.1, and give same results. What else could be?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the confusion Paola. In fact, the print-out will only be as I cited from 3.4.2 onwards (which will be released within the next couple of weeks). The information of spans is present in the `Example` also for older spaCy versions like 3.4.1, but it's not shown on print-out. PR https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/11261 actually added that behaviour.

Nevertheless - the code I cited should work fine. I will update my response to avoid further confusion though.

Comment: @SofieVL thanks for your answer, I am struggling with similar issue with spacy blank model and my custom labels. Any chance you can assist?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73764895/cant-run-the-spacy-spancat-spancategorizer-model

I am trying to train a spancat model, maybe you have an A-Z example?

Comment: Thanks Sofie. Will resume work on this in a few weeks. Hopefully by then will be able to make it work. Good luck Steve. regards,